# doubleclick back button cordova

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I'm trying to change the behavior of the back button on android devices. I'm using Cordova and wrote the following code that works:

```
function onLoad() {
  document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}

//device APIs are available
function onDeviceReady() {
  document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
}

//Backbutton
function onBackKeyDown() {
  location.href = "index.html";
}
```

now, what I see is that when I double click the back button the function onBackKeyDown() will be ignored.
Is there a way to fix this scenario?

EDIT

```
// Wait for device API libraries to load
function onLoad() {
  document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}

//device APIs are available
function onDeviceReady() {
  document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
}

document.addEventListener("backbutton", function (e){
    e.preventDefault();
    location.href = "index.html";
}, false);
```

Comment: searched for solutions but with no luck. not the best in javascript. currently in a speed course to learn it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to prevent the default `backbutton` event and to the do your custom navigation. Like this:

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", function (e){
    e.preventDefault();
    location.href = "index.html";
}, false);
```

Also you can check the following code: https://lloydzhou.github.io/project/2014/04/30/phonegap-exit-on-double-click-backbutton. It catches the single and double click.

Comment: made an edit to the question with the code i've got now. I might be real stupid here but i cant figgure out why its not working. I put your code in.

I looked at the link you sent. Its useful, but what I want to achieve with it is that the double click on the backbutton, counts as two clicks. or better disable the double click completely.

Comment: Add the new eventListener into `onDeviceReady()` function instead of `document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);` not outside ;)

Comment: Ah, that worked :p. 
When I spam the backbutton it still ignores it though. its not that much of a problem , but is there a way around that aswell?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "spam the backbutton"? Multiple clicks?

Comment: I thought that `e.preventDefault()` covers this case :( For now, I have no answer... later I can try some fixes ;)

Comment: it does cover it, i'll try to explain a scenario. From the 'homeschreen' you cant go back to the login screen via the backbutton on the device. that is because the preventDefault();. Now. when i go to a different screen in the app, and start clicking the backbutton quickly, first we go back to the homescreen, but then it goes to the login screen which should not happen. Hope that makes sence.